# vuetify Data Table: Is it possible to dynamically change the number of rows of the data table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

Is it possible to change dynamically to show all the rows of a data table and then again switch back to default, let's say the default is 50?

**My task is-**
Users want to export data to excel in the order where multiple columns are sorted. This was possible by manipulating the DOM but not possible if there are rows more than the default one.
So to do that, the user has to select `ALL` rows first in the footer to export all rows in excel, else it will export only the default 50 rows.

**My idea is-**
When a user clicks on the export button, it should dynamically change it to `ALL` rows and when export is completed, switch back the rows to the default which is 50.

Comment: Which version of Vuetify you are on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I figured it out in the documentation by reading the answer from @Neha, this prop needs to be in sync to have any changes to it and this can be done with .sync modifier. The only thing we need to add .sync after the prop like :items-per-page.sync, see code below:

**In template**

```
In template-

<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="rows"
  item-key="id"
  class="elevation-1"
  :items-per-page.sync="rowsPerPage"
>
</v-data-table>
```

**In script**

```
data() {
  return {
    rowsPerPage: 50,
  }
},

methods: {
  excelExportDOM() {
    this.rowsPerPage = -1;

    // do stuff

    this.rowsPerPage = 50;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this by utilizing the `items-per-page` prop which is available in both [Vuetify 2](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props) and [Vuetify 3](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-items-per-page). According to the documentation, the objective of this prop is-

> Changes in how many items per page should be visible. Can be used with
> .sync modifier. Setting this prop to -1 will display all items on the
> page.

That's it. When the user clicks on the export button, set this prop's value to **-1** which will show all rows, and when the export is finished, set its value again to your default which is 50.

Here is how you can accomplish this-

`In template-`

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="myItems"
  item-key="name"
  class="elevation-1"
  :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
>
</v-data-table>
```

`In script-`

```
data() {
  return {
    itemsPerPage: 50,
  }
},

methods: {
  exportDataToExcel() {
    this.itemsPerPage = -1;

    // WRITE HERE YOUR CODE TO EXPORT

    this.itemsPerPage = 50;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Neha, I tried this before even posting this question, it didnt work, where did you find this sentence, "Changes in how many items per page should be visible. Can be used with .sync modifier. Setting this prop to -1 will display all items on the page." can you please share the link ? I couldnt find in the docs. Many thanks for your help

Comment: I already attached the links. Can you explain more that how it didn't work?

Comment: It is available in the API's page props section. Look for that `item-per-page` prop's definition.

Comment: yes, found it, many thanks

Comment: we need to add .sync like items-per-page.sync: rowsPerPage

Comment: Well, you can upvote the answer if find it useful and accept it if its solve your problem.

Comment: well I will not unvote because it helped me but i cannot accept